# Optimize network range function

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, igraph, social-networking, micro-optimization

I found a [blog post](https://ramorel.github.io/network-range/) by Richard Paquin Morel on computing a network range function in R (Burt 1981; Reagans and McEvily 2003). The function assigns a value to each network node based on the number of its contacts and the interconnectedness of these nodes. The network range can be computed accross subgroups of nodes (e.g. female and male nodes). These are stored as attributes of the vertices.

The author's example is very illustrative, but it is based on a relatively small network (about 100 nodes). I have a network with about 200,000 nodes, which means the performance of the function is not suited for my analyses.

I present you an example where the size of a random graph according to the Erdos-Renyi model can be manipulated to time the performance of the functions.

I am unfamiliar with optimizing R code, but I think the adjacency matrix needs to be stored more efficiently (e.g., a sparse matrix). My attempts so far did not succeed in producing a working function.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(igraph)    
library(statnet)
library(intergraph)
library(tictoc)

set.seed(42)



## Source: https://ramorel.github.io/network-range/
## Function to find network range for each node in a network
## Arguments:
##  net = adjacency matrix, igraph graph, or network object
##  attr = Vector of attributes associated with each node in net
##  directed = boolean indicated if the network is directed or not


netrange <- function(net, attr, directed = TRUE){
  require(reshape2)
  if (class(net) == "igraph") {
    net <- as_adjacency_matrix(net, sparse = F)
  }
  else {
    if(class(net) == "network") {
      net <- as.matrix.network(net)
    }
    else {
      net <- as.matrix(net)
    }
  }
  if(nrow(net) != length(attr)) {
    stop("Number of nodes must match length of attributes vector")
  }
  else {
    if (directed == TRUE){
      ns <- colnames(net)
      el <- melt(net, varnames=c("ego", "alter"), value.name = "weight")
      df <- cbind(rownames(net), attr)
      el$ego_grp <- df[match(el[,1], df[,1]), 2]
      el$alter_grp <- df[match(el[,2], df[,1]), 2]
      
      #FINDING p_k, the strength of ties within each group
      # z_iq = sum of strength of ties from nodes in group _k_ to all other alters
      # z_ij = sum of strength of ties from nodes in group _k_ to alters in group _k_
      
      z_iq <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego_grp==x), "weight"])
      })
      z_ij <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego_grp==x & el$alter_grp==x), "weight"])
      })
      p_k <- z_ij / z_iq
      p_k[is.na(p_k)] <- 0
      
      #FINDING p_ik, the strength of connection from person i to group k
      # x_iq = sum of strength of ties for _i_ to alters in group _k_
      # x_ij = sum of strength of ties for _i_ to all alters
      
      x_ij <- sapply(colnames(net), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego==x), "weight"])
      }
      )
      x_iq <- list(NULL)
      for(i in colnames(net)) {
        x_iq[[i]] <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
          sum(el[which(el$ego==i & el$alter_grp==x), "weight"])
        }
        )
      }
      x_iq <- x_iq[-c(1)] #x_iq is now a list where each elements is a vector of node _i_ summed strength of tie to group _k_
      
      p_ik <- lapply(1:length(x_iq), 
                     function(x) x_iq[[x]] / x_ij[x])
      
      # FINDING nd_i, the network diversity score for node _i_
      
      nd_i <- sapply(1:length(p_ik), 
                     function(x) 1 - sum(p_k*p_ik[[x]]^2, na.rm = F)
      )
    }
    else {
      ns <- colnames(net)
      el <- melt(net, varnames=c("ego", "alter"), value.name = "weight")
      dup <- data.frame(t(apply(el[,1:2],1,sort)))
      
      el <- el[!duplicated(dup),]
      df <- cbind(rownames(net), attr)
      el$ego_grp <- df[match(el[,1], df[,1]), 2]
      el$alter_grp <- df[match(el[,2], df[,1]), 2]
      
      #FINDING p_k, the strength of ties within each group
      # z_iq = sum of strength of ties from nodes in group _k_ to all other alters
      # z_ij = sum of strength of ties from nodes in group _k_ to alters in group _k_
      
      z_iq <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego_grp==x | el$alter_grp==x), "weight"])
      })
      z_ij <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego_grp==x & el$alter_grp==x), "weight"])
      })
      p_k <- z_ij / z_iq
      p_k[is.na(p_k)] <- 0
      
      #FINDING p_ik, the strength of connection from person i to group k
      # x_iq = sum of strength of ties for _i_ to alters in group _k_
      # x_ij = sum of strength of ties for _i_ to all alters
      
      x_ij <- sapply(colnames(net), function(x) {
        sum(el[which(el$ego==x | el$alter==x), "weight"])
      }
      )
      x_iq <- list(NULL)
      for(i in colnames(net)) {
        x_iq[[i]] <- sapply(unique(attr), function(x) {
          sum(el[which(el$ego==i & el$alter_grp==x), "weight"],
              el[which(el$alter==i & el$ego_grp==x), "weight"])
        }
        )
      }
      x_iq <- x_iq[-c(1)] #x_iq is now a list where each elements is a vector of node _i_ summed strength of tie to group _k_
      
      p_ik <- lapply(1:length(x_iq), 
                     function(x) x_iq[[x]] / x_ij[x])
      
      
      # FINDING nd_i, the network diversity score for node _i_
      
      nd_i <- sapply(1:length(p_ik), 
                     function(x) 1 - sum(p_k*p_ik[[x]]^2, na.rm = F)
      )
    }
    return(nd_i)
  }
}


# Generate exemplary network

g <- igraph::erdos.renyi.game(1000, 150, type = "gnm")

## Add categorical (binary) vertex feature: female

V(g)$female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=length(V(g)))
V(g)$female


## transform igraph to statnet 

net <- intergraph::asNetwork(g)


## Apply network function 

tic()
range_female <- netrange(net, 
                         net %v% "female",
                         directed = T)
seq_time <- toc()
```

Comment: You have many for loops of type 'for each' here. R is optimized for vectorization. Can you calculate node properties for each node independently? If yes, you can use vectorization and also parallelization of multiple CPU cores e.g. using R packages `mclapply` or workflow frameworks like `targets`.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing to optimize is to use profiling using  `profvis` which shows where your bottle necks are. I took part of your function though.

There we saw `x_ij <- sapply(colnames(net), function(x) { sum(el[which(el$ego==x | el$alter==x), "weight"]) })` taking terribly long.

I prefer `data.table` myself so just provide the code here to speed up that part which takes a few seconds only. Try the same then for creating x_iq.

```
xx_ij <- el[, .(xxij = lapply(.SD, sum)), by = c("ego"), .SDcols = c("weight")]
xx_ij2 <- xx_ij$xxij
names(xx_ij2) <- xx_ij$ego

identical(x_ij, unlist(xx_ij2))
# TRUE
```

[image]

****profiling**

```
library(profvis)
p <- profvis({
  ## code here
})

f <- paste0("profile_", as.Date(now()), ".html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, f)
browseURL(f)
```

Comment: Thank you, Merijn! 
I did not now the profvis package so far. Very illustrative. 
I am unfamiliar with the data.table package but the speed advantage looks promising. I found [this guide](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/data-manipulation/datatable-in-r-complete-guide/) to be insightful (point 17). 

When I switch in your code snippet in the function, i get the following error:
`code`
profvis: code exited with error:
unused arguments (by = c("ego"), .SDcols = c("weight"))
`code`
Does it work on your machine? Maybe the data.table installation went wrong on our offline server.